# Newton's method and rearranging

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I am new to root-finding and using numerical methods.

> Using Newton's method below: $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_0)}$$ using this chord formula where the chord length $c$ is 1 cm: $$c=2r\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$$ supposing the radius is 1.1 cm and the angle θ is unknown, show the iterative Newton's Method equation you would use to find an approximate value for $\theta$ in the context of this problem (using the appropriate function and derivative).

I have tried rearranging it to $\theta$ but Symbolab gives me two solutions which add an $n$ to the equation. I found this equation but not sure if it right:$$\theta = 2\arcsin\frac{c}{2r}$$

But when I derive this, it becomes zero so I'm unsure if my equation is right either. I would just like help deriving this equation and then applying it to the problem.

Comment: You should not delete [closed questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3943053) and make new questions to avoid closures.

Answer (score 1):

You are expected to work with
$$
f(x)=c-2r\sin\frac x2\implies f'(x)=-r\cos\frac x2
$$
and indeed this equation has multiple solutions. You need to pick the one in the correct interval, what that is comes from additional knowledge about the geometrical situation. One could for instance ask for the smallest positive solution, which will be inside the interval $[0,\pi]$ if $0<c<2r$.

Comment: How would you approximate for theta in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I replaced $θ$ with $x$ to be closer to the Newton method formula that you wrote down. Your formula with the arcus sinus is correct, I think the idea for this task is that you should pretend that you have a sine function available, but not the inverse function of it.

Comment: The task is to use the iterative Newton's Method equation to find the approximate value of theta. However since there is theta in the equation you work with (in this case x) how would you find the approximate value of theta or x?

Comment: I heard you have to differentiate with respect to x

Comment: So that has me thinking, is there a initial guess for x, that is within the interval you said

Comment: You could take the secant root over the interval, or just start at 0, ... There is no intrinsic guarantee that the method converges, and even if, that it converges to a root close to the starting point. This needs to be controlled externally, for instance by restarting with a different value in the interval.